# Size of objects and variations in brightness?

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, astrophysics, speed-of-light

My textbook says talking about Cygnus X-1 (the first black hole to be identified as such) has variations in brightens of the order of 0.01 seconds and that this means that it's dimeter must be on the order of 3000km (=speed of light times 0.01). Why must this be so? The reason I asked is could (if it was not a black hole) it just not have vary active outer layers and be much larger. What the above seems to imply is that the light must be able to travel from one side of the source to the other in the time between differences in intensity. But I can not see why this should be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variations you mention are variations in the brightness of X-rays emitted by Cygnus X-1, and we expect the X-rays to be emitted towards the inner edge of the [accretion disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygnus_X-1#Accretion_disk). As matter swirls in towards the event horizon it is heated and ionised and this causes it to emit X-rays. So when there's an increase in brightness it probably means more than the usual amount of matter is reaching the inner edge of the accretion disk, and when there's a decrease in brightness this probably means less matter than usual is flowing in.

Now, if different parts of the accretion disk were changing brightness randomly we expect they would cancel each other out. That is, some bits would be brighter than usual, some would be darker than usual, and on average the brightness wouldn't change much. If we see a big change of brightness this suggests the disk as a whole is getting brighter or dimmer, and it is doing so due to some external stimulus.

But if the brightness changes within some time $t$ the external stimulus must be affecting the whole accretion disk within some time $t$. Since nothing can travel faster than light this means the whole disk must have a size of less than $ct$.

It's not impossible that the fluctuations are due to small areas of the disk, so we can't be absolutely sure that the size limit is $ct$, but it seems highly probable.

Answer (score 0):

The processes occurring in the accretion disc near a black hole are in general unknown to us at the moment, we are using models and try to match the observed data. Astrophysicists use in such cases the principle of causality to estimate the size of the source, namely that if a change of state occurs at the core, the lower bound of time it will take  to reach the boundary of the object is the size of the object divided by the speed of light. For compact sources, this is the best estimate we obtain from first principles without imposing several other assumptions, which correspond to models such as the Shakura & Sunyaev model, ADAFs, cooling flows etc.